# Android: how to have a localbroadcast reciever inside service

Tags: android, android-service, localbroadcastmanager

I have service in which I want to have a localbroadcast receiver. I want to recieve a value from the activity to my services onCreate.

Note: I can get a value from an activity to my service in onStartCommand() using intent. But here I want a value from activity in onCreate of the service.

The following is my service file:

```
    public class MediaServiceSimha extends Service {

        private MediaPlayer player;
        String musicpath;
        private ResponseReceiver receiver;

        public MediaServiceSimha() {}

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
            localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
            return super.onUnbind(intent);
        }

        @
        Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            player.start();
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter("com.example.myintentserviceapp.intent_service.ALL_DONE");
            receiver = new ResponseReceiver();
            LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
            localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(receiver, broadcastFilter);
        }

        public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                musicpath = intent.getStringExtra("musicpath");
            }
        }
    }
```

The following is my activity file where I want to pass a value called musicpath

```
public class ServiceTest extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent intent;

    public static final String TEXT_INPUT = "inText";
    //MediaServiceSimha mediaServiceSimha;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        L.m("activity_oncreate_starting");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_service_test);
        intent= new Intent(this,MediaServiceSimha.class);

        startService(intent);

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("com.example.myintentserviceapp.intent_service.ALL_DONE");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("musicpath", "/storage/emulated/0/Download/1.mp3");
        LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent)
    }


}
```

After running, it says musicpath value is null.

How to do it?

Comment: you dont need it at all: pass "musicpath" in extras when calling `startService`

Comment: i'm very confused by your question: the fact you are registering the broadcast receiver in onCreate of your service doesn't mean you'll receive the intent there.  simply pass whatever information you need in the intent each time you need to using startService...

Comment: But why are you doing this? If you really want to pass PATH to service then put it on `Extra(..) `and receive in service

Comment: when you are calling start service it doesn't mean it will call immediately,so wait for oncreate of service,whenever you get callback from service at that time you can send broadcast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal was to pass a variable value directly to oncreate in the service class.

I tried LocalBroadcast's reciver and also onbindservices - onServiceConnected

Both of them i found that they will only get executed untill oncreate -> onbind/onstartcommand get executed in the services.

So only option left is onstartcommand()

So when we pass values using intent then they can be used immediately inside onstartcommand.

Answer (score -1):

when you are calling start service it doesn't mean it will call immediately,so wait for oncreate of service,whenever your service getstarted you can send a callback to your activity then you can broadcast values to your service

```
       public service callback()  // callback from service started
        {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                broadcastIntent.setAction("com.example.myintentserviceapp.intent_service.ALL_DONE");
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("musicpath", "/storage/emulated/0/Download/1.mp3");
                LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
                localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent)
        } 


      public class MediaServiceSimha extends Service {
      @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();
                IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter("com.example.myintentserviceapp.intent_service.ALL_DONE");
                receiver = new ResponseReceiver();
                LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
                localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(receiver, broadcastFilter);
              sendCallback(); // using interface or broadcast receiver to send callback to activity
            }

}
```

Comment: what does the comment `//using interface or broadcast receiver to send callback to activity` mean. First time i am coming across `public service callback()`. I am completely new to this. can you help me more about these

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi you dont need `LocalBroadcastManager` at all: just pass "musicpath" in extras when calling `startService`

Comment: But i want to use the musicpath in the oncreate and not in the onstartcommand(). onCreate starts first and then onstartcommand

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi so you need to change your design, whats wrong with passing it in the `Intent`'s extras?

Comment: becaue i want to start the mediaplayer inside oncreate

Comment: I tried the above solution, i used localbroadcast as a callback, the problem i am facing is, after executing code in onCreate, it goes to onStartcommand, after that only it goes to onRecieve. When i called sendbroadcast() inside onCreate, i was expecting it will go to  onRecieve, rather it goes to onStartcommand and only after that it goes to onRecieve

Comment: I have seen many media players. where they have started the mediaplayer inside onCreate. But they used bindingservice, they passed the musicpath from the activity. Instead of that i want to achieve it through localbroadcast

Comment: in oncreate of service you will get service instance,just make service as singleton,create some methods in service,whenever you want call methods you can call using service instance

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi whats the difference where you `start()`ing the `MediaPlayer`? and of course the service has to be "local bound service" to easily talk to/from the client activity

Comment: I decided to use bindservice() to pass variables to oncreate from activity

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi actually `bindService` should be used for binding only, for passing any data you should use Service's `IBinder` object